# Troubleshooting BSOD error 0x000000c5 (0x00010003, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0xB05515A1) on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

A BSOD error **0x000000c5 (0x00010003, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0xB05515A1)** occurred in Windows XP while my device was running. After power cycling also the error persisted. I tried to boot into safe mode, but the device reboots. Please provide a way to understand and troubleshoot the issue.

[image]

Comment: Have you recently updated a device driver?

Comment: @spikey_richie I have not done any updates.

Comment: Try starting with a bootable USB Key and then see if you can see the XP drive.  The drive may have failed.

Comment: What's the stop code? (usually in the second paragraph)

Comment: @user1242067 Stop code - 0x000000c5 (0x00010003, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0xB05515A1)